# JPA Loadgraph and Caching - properties not fetched

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We use Wildfly 8.2 and hence JEE 7 with the feature of [JPA 2.1 Loadgraphs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm#sthref2182).

Assume, we have the following, hierarchical entity structure (abbreviated classes):

```
@Entity
public class IsEntity {
    @Id private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private IsEntity parentIsEntity;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "IS_SHOULD", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "IS_ID") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SHOULD_ID", unique = true) }, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                name = "FK_SHOULD_ID"),
        inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_IS_SHOULD"))
    private ShouldEntity    shouldEntity;
}

@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "withShouldParent", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("parentShouldEntity") }),
public class ShouldEntity {
    @Id private Long id;

    @Column
    private String someProperty;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_SHOULD_PARENT"))
    private ShouldEntity parentShouldEntity;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "shouldEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "IS_SHOULD", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SHOULD_ID") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "IS_ID", unique = true) }, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                name = "FK_IS_SHOULD"),
        inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_SHOULD_IS"))
    private IsEntity    isEntity;
}
```

The functional requirement behind this structure is, that we are modelling the hierarchical structure on the "should"-side first and creating the respective "is" side in the process.

Given, I have the following entities:

```
IsEntity(id = 10, shouldEntityId = 20, parentIsEntity = null)
ShouldEntity(id = 20, isEntityId = 10, parentShouldEntity = null, someProperty = "firstShouldParent")
ShouldEntity(id = 21, isEntityId = null, parentShouldEntity = 20, someProperty = "firstShouldChild")
```

Now I execute the following two queries:

```
entityManager.find(IsEntity.class, 10); // IsEntityQuery

EntityGraph loadGraph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("withShouldParent");
Map<String, Object> queryHints = new HashMap<>();
queryHints.put( "javax.persistence.loadgraph", loadGraph );
ShouldEntity loadedEntity = entityManager().find( ShouldEntity.class, 21, queryHints ) );
```

And the following call on the queried object crashes:

```
loadedEntity.getParentShouldEntity().getSomeProperty();
```

The error message is:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   de.somecompany.ShouldEntity_$$_jvst757_14 cannot be cast to
>   de.somecompany.ShouldEntity

If I omit the `IsEntityQuery`, the `ShouldEntity` and its parent are loaded correctly! It hence seems, that there seems to be a problem with the first level cache (?) and JPA load graphs, if the load graphs should load an entity which has already been seen by the entity manager. IMHO, the entity manager should be clever enough to realize, that the `ShouldEntity(id=20)` was only lazily loaded when querying the `IsEntity` and that it must be eagerly fetched as described by the load graph. At least that is what I read from the specification, chapter 3.7.4.2:

> If the attribute is a one-to-one  or many-to-one relationship, and 
>   the attribute is specified in an attribute node, the default fetch
>   graph of the target  entity is fetched

So, my question basically is: Is the behaviour expected, maybe even described somewhere, is it a bug in Hibernate 4.3.7 (as shipped with WildFly 8.2.0) or is it a missing piece in the JPA specification?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The exact problem I am facing. Did you discover anything about this?

Comment: All I can say is that _maybe_ putting `em.clear()` after the `find()` will make it work. (although the question was not about this)

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa: I honestly can't remember because I switched jobs ... But maybe it works with a newer version of WildFly? Could you provide the exact versions you are using for others who may hit this question?

Comment: Hibernate 5.0.4 and JPA 2.1. No WildFly, but the problem is the same.